# How to use MySQL-Connector-C++ in a brew environment in Sierra?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, mysql

I have been trying to test a code to connect to MySQL using C++ on a MacBook Pro, but I always get an error about boost/filename.hpp not found. I fix that by adding a full path on e.g. `/usr/local/boost_1_64_0/boost/filename.hpp`.

This fixes an error for one #include, when I compile again I get the same error on another line.

It will take me forever to do that (correcting the path all the time). I then downloaded MySQL-Connector-C++ using brew - which is now located at /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c++/1.1.9/.

Within the Cellar folder there are boost, mysql, openssl directories.

Can anyone please tell me how I can use this to test my code, run a simple query, and where do I put my c++ file I've created and need to compile?

I have written the code but I can't test it, it's private and for an organization which gave me the task.

I have been trying to figure out how to avoid correcting paths for more than three days now, followed all the instructions from the manual from the MySQL website.

Comment: @patrix I don't think it's about sw-dev. It's more about software installation and proper configuration.

Comment: I use MacBook Pro mid 2012

Comment: @klanomath I read it as about not knowing how to add additional include and library paths to whatever command/compiler the OP is using to compile their code, and most probably some other stuff. It will take some back and forth with clarifications and details on either site, still think SO is more suited for this.

Comment: running on MacOS Sierra 10.12.5, 13"

Comment: How do you compile your code? In Xcode, with a makefile or somehow else?

Comment: @patrix I use the terminal,

Comment: patrix I am ok with coding.

Comment: these are the steps i followed trying to install the mysql-connector-c++, first I installed, mysql c api, then Cmake using bootstrap, then glib, then i installed boost_1_64_0, it shows errors when i run this: cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost_1_64_0. i believe that is where my problem starts.

Comment: Lets get this to stack overflow. The experts there have great guidance on how to get a sample reproducible case and brew / command line use of `cmake` is on topic there too.